# Full Bridge Inverter with transformer, source current waveform

Tags: transformer, simulation, matlab, full-bridge

I intend to make a 750W DC/AC inverter working with a 24V DC supply. I have simulated the circuit in MatLab using PLCECS toolbox.

Here i use a 50kHz carrier to generate a 50Hz modulated unipolar PWM signal to drive the full bridge. PLECS circuit include a full bridge, a high frequency step up transformer and a LC filter as in the following figure.[image]

Problem is when i monitor the current drawn from the source it is higher than the expected maximum value of 60A and there is a a current in the negative direction as in the bottom plot of the following diagram. [image]
What are the reasons for this and how will it affect if i make this circuit?

Comment: Where's the rectifier bridge on your secondary?

Comment: There is none. I am getting a 50Hz AC output on R1.

Comment: What current do you get? What are the waveforms representing?

Comment: So … why do you expect only positive currents?

Comment: The upper waveform is the voltage of the transformer primary. Lower waveform is the current drained from the DC voltage source. I want only positive currents because if not the current will go into the voltage source, instead of coming from it.